# Matlab Connector/J really slow; running query directly is much faster

Tags: mysql, matlab

I need to repeatedly run large queries and store/manipulate the results in Matlab.  I am using Connector/J (mysql-connector-java-5.1.25 driver) to connect to the mySQL server (which is located on my local machine).  The query I run creates a ~140 MB cell array with the data (I have included the query code and the `CREATE` code for the table at the bottom of this post).  Executing this query and creating the cell array takes approximately 10 seconds.  Running the same query in HeidiSQL and displaying all the results takes only 0.2 seconds.

When I run a simple `select count(*) from (<current query>)` in Matlab (ie. when I don't create the cell array to store the query results), the statements take only 0.3 seconds to execute, so I'm led to believe the significant time increase experienced in Matlab has to do with writing so much data to a cell array.

Is there any way to speed this process up in Matlab?

**My code:**

I have the following table in mySQL (`CREATE` code taken from HeidiSQL; some field names were changed):

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
    `PRIMARY` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ID` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `DATE` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `PRICE` DECIMAL(14,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `QUANT` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `TIME` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `DATE` (`DATE`),
    INDEX `ID` (`SYMBOL`),
    INDEX `PRICE` (`PRICE`),
    INDEX `QUANT` (`SIZE`),
    INDEX `TIME` (`TIME`),
    PRIMARY KEY (`PRIMARY`)
)
```

It is populated with approximately 360,000 rows of data.

The query I'm running is:

```
Select ID, DATE, PRICE, QUANT, TIME FROM database.data WHERE DATE 
>= "2007-01-01" AND DATE <= "2010-12-31" ORDER BY ID, DATE, TIME ASC;
```

This returns about 260,000 rows. By the way, removing the `ORDER BY` statement does not speed up the query.

In Matlab, I use the following code to execute the query and store the results:

```
MyCellArray = fetch(dbConn, IntradayQUERY);
```

where `dcConn` is the database connection object and `IntradayQUERY` is a string containing the query statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try is to increasing the row increment in the `fetch` function.  This reduces the number of times that Matlab goes extracts data from the results, and also reduces the amount of memory reallocation required.  The default value is 1280.  I would go much, much larger, until your computer runs out of memory.  Try 10,000, 100,000, or even 500,000.  If you start running out of memory, consider selecting fewer columns (as your application allows, of course).

For example, replace `MyCellArray = fetch(dbConn, IntradayQUERY);` with `MyCellArray = fetch(dbConn, IntradayQUERY, 100000);` and see what happens.

Comment: 50,000 seems to cut the run time in half.  Going higher increases the time to run; I get errors around 200,000.  Any idea why the run time would actually increase above 50,000?